# Touch event doesn't alert latitude

Tags: javascript, dom-events, webgl-earth

I'm trying to use WebGL Earth 2.0 in one of my new projects. The library

can be found here: https://github.com/webglearth/webglearth2

**- Let say I want to click on the globe and the browser must alert me back 
the latitude of the place that I have clicked. What I did was this:**

```
earth.on('click', fire);

var fire = function(e) {

alert('You clicked at ' +e.latitude);
};
```

It worked on the web browser and returned the latitude, but it did not work on the mobile( iPhone ) browser.

so what I did next was this instead:

```
 earth.on('touchstart', fire);

 var fire = function(e) {

    alert('You clicked at ' +e.latitude);
    };
```

It works on the mobile browser (iPhone), but the problem is it doesn't return latitude. Instead it alerts me with "NULL". I want it to return the latitude when I touch the globe in the mobile browser.

Please help me to make it work like I want...

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon this while testing/researching WebGL Earth. It seems as if they fixed it over the last year using the lat/lng - values should work.

Comment: But as I just read, you already solved it by issuing it on Github.

Comment: Watch out that the initial fix is only for the touchstart event.